# Самая длинная общая часть / longest common part

Tags: php

Добрый вечер, есть код который выводит самую длинную часть в двух словах, в данном случае "ааа". Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать, чтобы в случае нескольких таких частей они все выводились. Конкретно здесь "ааа" и "оо"

```
$array = array(
    'Argoolaaa',
    'Banaaanoo' );

function longestCommonPart($words) {

    $words = array_map('strtolower', array_map('trim', $words));
    $sort_by_strlen = create_function('$a, $b', 'if (strlen($a) == strlen($b))
    { return strcmp($a, $b); } return (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) ? -1 : 1;');
    usort($words, $sort_by_strlen);

    $longestCommonPart = array();
    $shortest_string = str_split(array_shift($words));

    while (sizeof($shortest_string)) {
        array_unshift($longestCommonPart, '');
        foreach ($shortest_string as $ci => $char) {
            foreach ($words as $wi => $word) {
                if (!strstr($word, $longestCommonPart[0] . $char)) {

                    break 2;
                }
            }
            $longestCommonPart[0] .= $char;
        }
        array_shift($shortest_string);
    }

    usort($longestCommonPart, $sort_by_strlen);
    return array_pop($longestCommonPart); }

echo longestCommonPart($array);
```

Comment: Необходимо уточнить условие, самая длинная часть в этих словах - `aaa`, откуда взялось - `оо`?

Comment: "oo" это вторая совпадающая часть. Мне необходимо вывести обе эти части. А выводит лишь лишь одну совпадающую часть

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно вывести 2 или более одинаковые буквы стоящие рядом и  присутствующие во всех словах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом примере будут найдены повторяющиеся буквы, расположенные рядом друг с другом, начиная от двух и более совпадений, и при условии, что эти совпадения есть более чем в одном слове

```
<?php

$text = 'Добрый ввеер, еесть код котооорый вывооодит...';
var_dump( check_matches($text) );


function check_matches($text, $array = [], $result = []) {
    foreach (explode(' ', $text) as  $word) {
        preg_match_all('~(\pL)\1+~u', $word, $arr);
        !$arr[0] ?: $array[] = $arr[0];
    }

    do {
        $first_array = array_shift($array);
        foreach ($array as $arr) {
            foreach (array_intersect($first_array, $arr) as $val) {
                $result[] = $val;
            }
        }
    } while (count($array));

    return array_unique($result);
}
```

Результат:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'ее' (length=4)
  1 => string 'ооо' (length=6)
```

Comment: Отличное решение! Вопрос, когда в нескольких словах подряд идет совпадение по повторяющимся буквам, вывод идет одной строкой 

    $text = 'Vaasiooo kaatnalooo';
    array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "aaooo" }

Comment: @AndriiShchur подкорректировал свой ответ.

Comment: Супер. Спасибо!

Comment: @AndriiShchur если мой ответ вам подходит, вы можете отметить его галкой.

Answer (score -1):

Доброе время суток.
Честно лень было вникать в код, но через регулярные выражения решается достаточно просто. Если я правильно понял

```
$array = array(
    'Argoolaaa',
    'Banaaanoo'
);
$pattern = "#(.)\\1{1,}#m";
foreach ($array as $el) {
    $mattches = [];
    preg_match_all($pattern, $el, $mattches);
    foreach ($mattches[0] as $f) {
        echo $f . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня не работает этот код

Comment: Что выдает скрипт?

Comment: Извините, моя ошибка. Работает. Только данный код  выводит все совпадающие части по порядку. "oo
aaa
aaa
oo"

Comment: А дальше уже на ваше усмотрение, можно выбрать уникальные или еще чего. К примеру можно все значения собрать в массив `$res` и выбрать уникальные данные оттуда `$res = array_unique($res)`
Основная цель достигнута, это в словах выбор длинных частей в слове.